# mod_rewrite rule: if URL contains a certain string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My client keeps editing the structure of the navigation in the website, which is leading to some mod_rewrite issues. How could i make this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^studios/about-studios/artist-noticeboard noticeboard2.php?section=studios&subSection=studio-artists [L]
```

to work if the url contains `"noticeboard"`? Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^IF CONTAINS 'noticeboard' noticeboard2.php?section=studios&subSection=studio-artists [L]
```

Any pointers welcome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/noticeboard2\.php$
RewriteRule noticeboard noticeboard2.php?section=studios&subSection=studio-artists [L]
```

This rule will rewrite any request that contains “noticeboard” in the URL path to *noticeboard2.php* in the same directory.

Comment: And what do I have to specify if I DON'T want to rewrite id url contains noticeboard

Comment: @Sergey Invert the `RewriteRule` pattern with `!`.

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved related problem. It's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258698/apache-tomcat-apache-httpd-mod-proxy-mod-rewrite-form-post-data

Comment: ...maybe obvious, but I would also point out that this rewrites any request that contains "noticeboard" UNLESS it exactly equals /noticeboard2.php as per the RewriteCond.