# apache tomcat + apache httpd + mod_proxy + mod_rewrite + form post data

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-post, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

please help me. I did try to find similar problem here reading old posts, but I didn't find anything.
I have a problem with post data.
I'm using Apache tomcat + ajp +  Apache Httpd 2.2
Here is a part of my **httpd.conf**:

```
#Application has context url = konakart, and tomcat post 8789 for ajp
#I want to avoid typing port in my URL
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8789/konakart/

#pretty urls
#I don't want to type http://myshop.com/konakart
#I want http://myshop.com
#I want to put away /konakart/ from URL
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteRule ^/konakart/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule send-mail index.php?send-mail [NC,P]
```

Everyting is ok... except that from POST data is lost.
Seems like it's because of R=301. But I can't put away R=301. If I do so nothing works.
I'm using VDS so I can do anything...
please help me to overcome this problem .:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was combined problem of mod_rewrite and GWT and my curl hands ;)
Here is valid httpd.conf code, see comments in code:

```
    #Tomcat through Apache httpd
    ProxyPass /konakart ajp://localhost:8789/konakart
    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8789/konakart/

    #pretty urls

    RewriteEngine on
    Options +FollowSymlinks
#do not do anything for POST actions and GWT stuff. It's better not to touch it at all.
#mod_rewrite breaks interconnection of GWT RPC calls.
    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !/(.*)EditCartSubmit\.do(.*)
    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !/(.*)Submit\.do(.*)
    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !/(.*)\.cache\.html
    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !/(.*)\.nocache\.(.*)\.js
#Previously GWT servlet had mapping "/konakart"
#I've renamed it to "/KonakartGWTServlet"
    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !/KonakartGWTServlet
    RewriteRule ^/konakart/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```