# htaccess redirection to by unique word in homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect all Url which contain "forums" in address bar!!

Like:http://www.sportsinjuryclinic.net/blog/forums/ to http://www.sportsinjuryclinic.net Can any one help me to do that redirection?

Thanks

Comment: Is `/blog/forums` a real directory?

Comment: No this directory does not exist?? Can you give me a better suggestion?

Comment: ok is `/blogs/` a real directory?

Comment: Yes /blog/ is real directory..Thanks...I really very confuse

Comment: Site made  in joomla and it contains wordpress blog

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Mod_rewrite and a regex to check for the "forums" string. Here is an example of what you're looking for.
[mod_rewrite rule: if URL contains a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363140/mod-rewrite-rule-if-url-contains-a-certain-string)

Comment: How can i set it for above link.

Comment: How can i use it for all query string in url??

Answer (score 0):

#### Rule 1:

If `/blog/` is a directory then place this rule in `/blog/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteRule ^forums(/.*)?$ / [L,NC,R=302]
```

#### Rule 2:

For handling `/forums/ place this rule in`DocuementRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^forums(/.*)?$ / [L,NC,R=302]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: This link will redirect to home page?

Comment: I have to redirect thousand of url..is it working for specific word?

Comment: if i want to redirect url like: "/forum/archive/index.php/f-12.html" there are thousand url like this how can i redirect it to home page?

Comment: I got your point but this link is diffrent this does not contain /blog/forum/ it only contain /forum/

Comment: ok I have added 2 rules in my answer. One for `/blog/forums` and another for `/forums`. Pay attention to in which .htaccess they go to.

Comment: You must place both rules as **very first rules** in root .htaccess and `/blog/.htaccess`

Comment: Yes Working Perfect!! Thanks...If i want to redirect on http://www.sportsinjuryclinic.net/test how can i pass it ?

Comment: You can use: `RewriteRule ^test(/.*)?$ / [L,NC,R=302]`

Comment: Also if it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.