# htaccess how to rewrite url if url exists string

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my url with htaccess, when URL contains a certain string.

Example:

```
My url : example.com/information
```

When "information" is in my url, I want to rewrite to my information.php file.
Hope anyone can help me out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4026967/6124528

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/information\.php$
RewriteRule information information.php [L]
```

This rule will rewrite any request that contains “information” in the URL path to information.php in the same directory.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363140/mod-rewrite-rule-if-url-contains-a-certain-string)